# Here Map Navigation not working in Picture in Picture Mode for Android

Tags: android, here-api, android-picture-in-picture, heremaps, heremap-navigation

I am trying to implement Picture in Picture mode for Here Map navigation. I am facing one problem, Map is not updating its camera in PIP mode. Voice instruction and all other instructions are working fine. When i switch to PIP mode map camera is not updating.When i go back to normal mode everything works fine.

Is there any special handling need for HereMap navigation. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened an issue for this problem and official says current version don't support **Picture in Picture** mode. They will consider supporting this in next release. 
Here is the [issue](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/issues/365) link.